# How can I turn an LED on only at 24 V ± 1 V?

Tags: led, led-driver

Is it possible to make a circuit so an LED turns on at a specific voltage?
My requirement is to indicate whether 24 VDC is available at the pcb or not (used as a power supply indication.)
I want the LED to light up at precisely 24V (± 1V tolerance) and I tried with a voltage divider circuit but I can only limit at lower side(5,12,21 V) not at the higher. Once the 24V drop across the LED it starts to glow even 28V as an input voltage.

Comment: You can use a voltage divider with a buffer amplifier. Choose the right resistors to get the range of current needed. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJNJ3.png

Comment: A comparator circuit comes to mind here.....

Comment: Do you want to detect 24V vs. no voltage? Or you want to light up LED only if there is precisely 24V, and not when it is over 24V (25, 48 etc.) or less then 24V (3, 5, 12, etc.)?

Comment: i want to light up LED is precisely at 24V(+/-1V tolerance) . and i try with voltage divider circuit but i can only limit at lower side(5,12,21 V) not at higher. once the 24V drop across the led it start to glow even 28V as an input voltage

Comment: @Raj_1 this is very important. Add this information to your question.

Comment: "I want to light up LED is precisely at 24V(+/-1V tolerance)". Lookup window comparator on  your favorite search engine.

Comment: A window comparator is _precisely_ what you're looking for. +1 to @WarrenHill

Answer (score 4):

Here is a circuit that can detect the input supply voltage between ~23V to ~25V and illuminate an LED when the voltage is within that range. Of course resistor tolerances will make this range vary slightly and as a matter of fact with the exact values given simulation shows the range to be 23.2V to 25.3V.

The circuit uses a 2.5V shunt reference part. The part number shown is a reference that was available in the simulation tool library. A different 2.5V reference (such as a low cost TL431) could be used or select a reference of another voltage and adjust the resistor values accordingly.

The circuit is also setup to allow about 10mA of current through the LED. If you have a high efficiency LED that current could be reduced by adjusting the R7 value.

[image]

Comment: The hard to get expensive LT1634 is overkill for lighting an LED. A tl431 or even a zener might be sufficient, since reference goes to high impedance inputs of LM393.

Comment: @Indraneel - Please read what I said regarding the reference in my answer. There is really no reason to have to criticize this point.

Comment: @Michael_Karas Sorry! You are right. But... A higher voltage zener (for higher accuracy) would have been a better choice for the schematic.

Comment: @Indraneel If you were to use just a zener, the schematic would otherwise look the same, wouldn't it? Save for just a few resistor value tweaks.

Comment: +1 LM4040 series is another nice shunt reference series. Might want to consider a zener in series with the LED if the circuit lights the LED dimly with very low Vin.

Comment: @Michael_Karas Yes, and one extra resistor between R1 and R2.

Comment: @indianareel - why add another resistor?

Answer (score 1):

The TL431 is the go to component here.

This first circuit turns the LED on above a certain voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFGp63.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've drawn it as an NPN transistor for two reasons.

1) The schematic editor doesn't have the right symbol for the TL431

2) It *behaves* like an NPN transistor, with a very accurately defined, temperature stable VBE of 2.5v. This part is ubiquitous as an accurate output voltage sensor in power supplies.

If you tried this trick with an ordinary NPN, you would find that the '0.7v' VBE would vary between transistor types, between parts of the same type, with temperature, and with collector current. You would have a very inaccurate switch-on point.

R1/R2 provide a roughly 10:1 pot down to turn 24v into the 2.5v needed. R4 can trim it to be spot on. Or you can omit R4, and set R1 and R2 exactly to get the right division ratio.

R3 limits the LED current when it turns on.

However, the OP wants a window comparator, where the LED is on only between certain voltages. This can be achieved by building on the previous circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMdE3q.png)</sup>

Set the R1,2,4 voltage divider to deliver the 2.5v trip voltage at 23v. Below 23v, the LED will be off, above 23v, the LED will be on.

Set the R5,6,7 voltage divider to deliver the 2.5v trip voltage at 25v input. When the input voltage exceeds 25v, Q2 conducts, which pulls the trip voltage down at Q1, and turns the LED off.

Is this a sensible use of TL431s? Maybe, if you have a drawer full of them. Most people would construct a window comparator from an LM339 and a reference, using much the same principles.

Comment: This will light up LED even when there is more than 24V. Which is not wanted.

Comment: It's not my question.

Comment: @Chupacabras yes, it's not is it. Oops, my bad.

Comment: A TL431 behaves like a NPN transistor *somewhat*.  Showing a TL431 as a NPN in a schematic is incorrect, misleading, and gives others bad ideas.  Two major differences are the B-E drop and the off-state leakage.  Note that this current actually powers the device.  This current is enough to dimly light LEDs, so matters in this case.  -1.  This can be fixed by resistor around the LED.  Your concept is otherwise good, so +1.  +0 overall.